# Always including the user in the django template context

Tags: python, django, authentication, session, cookies

I am working on a small intranet site for a small company, where user should be able to post. I have imagined a very simple authentication mechanism where people just enter their email address, and gets sent a unique login url, that sets a cookie that will always identify them for future requests.

In my template setup, I have base.html, and the other pages extend this. I want to show logged in or register button in the base.html, but how can I ensure that the necessary variables are always a part of the context? It seems that each view just sets up the context as they like, and there is no global context population. Is there a way of doing this without including the user in each context creation?

Or will I have to make my own custom shortcuts to setup the context properly?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In a more general sense of not having to explicitly set variables in each view, it sounds like you want to look at writing your own [context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

From the docs:

> A context processor has a very simple interface: It's just a Python function that takes one argument, an HttpRequest object, and returns a dictionary that gets added to the template context. Each context processor must return a dictionary.

Answer (score 46):

There is **no need** to write a context processor for the user object if you already have the [`"django.core.context_processors.auth"`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates) in [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) **and** if you're using [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) in your views.

if you are using django 1.4 or latest the module has been moved to `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`

Comment: This template context variable is not available if a RequestContext is not being used.

Comment: True, you have to use [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)

Comment: Use render() (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) from Django 1.3 to always include RequestContext automatically.

Comment: The first link should be: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates

Answer (score 33):

@Ryan: Documentation about preprocessors is a bit small

@Staale: Adding user to the Context every time one is calling the template in view, DRY

Solution is to use a preprocessor

**A**: In your settings add

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'myapp.processor_file_name.user',
)
```

**B**: In myapp/processor_file_name.py insert

```
def user(request):
    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        return {'user':request.user }
    return {}
```

From now on you're able to use user object functionalities in your templates.

```
{{ user.get_full_name }}
```

Comment: Django gives the error `Put 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' in your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting in order to use the admin application.` And even if I do that, the templates still doesn't know about `user`.

Comment: @hobbes3 since you are not using RequestContext the context processors do not get executed.

Comment: @rebus Actually in my `views.py`, I passing along a simple dictionary using `render_to_resposne` as oppose to a `RequestContext`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

The hints are in every answer, but once again, from "scratch", for newbies:

authentication data is in templates (almost) by default -- with a small trick:

in `views.py`:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
...
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', 
                              {'var': 'value'},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in `index.html`:

```
...
Hi, {{ user.username }}
var: {{ value }}
...
```

From here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates

> This template context variable is not available if a **RequestContext** is
>   not being used.

Answer (score 2):

If you can hook your authentication into the [Django authentication scheme](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/authentication/#authentication-in-web-requests) you'll be able to use `request.user`.

I think this should just be a case of calling `authenticate()` and `login()` based on the contents of your Cookie.

Edit: @Staale - I always use the [`locals()` trick](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter04/) for my context so all my templates can see `request` and so `request.user`.  If you're not then I guess it wouldn't be so straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

@Dave
To use {{user.username}} in my templates, I will then have to use 
requestcontext rather than just a normal map/hash: http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/templates_python/#subclassing-context-requestcontext

So I guess there are no globals that the template engine checks.

But the RequestContext has some prepopulate classes that I can look into to solve my problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

its possible by default, by doing the following steps, ensure you have added the context 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' in your settings. By default its added in settings.py, so its looks like this

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.core.context_processors.request',
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.core.context_processors.auth',)
```

And you can access user object like this,

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

For more information, refer here http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates

Comment: You also need to use RequestContext instead of Context in this case.

Comment: This is now outdated, see @synkc's answer below

Answer (score 0):

Use context_processors. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-OPTIONS

> settings.py

```
'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'myapp.functions.test'
        ],
},
```

> myapp/functions.py

```
def test(request):
    return {'misc': 'misc'}
```