# When to use context processor

Tags: django, django-templates, django-context

I have a site on which I'm including a userBox with some data shown for each logged user (your name, avatar etc). From what I already know about django it seems obvious, that I should add query for user to context processor (so that I can use`{{user}}` variable in this included userBox ). But while using django-lfs shop I've noticed, that it's templates are using `{{ user }}` variable which is nowhere added to context processors nor template tags. Is there any other way to obtain user in my template than those 2 ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547/always-including-the-user-in-the-django-template-context

Comment: I guess that's it in this topic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's added by

```
django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth
```

And the answer for the question is: if you need something to be in every template, you should use context_processor.

Comment: ok but will using {{user}} from auth context processor allow me to include avatar of user or can I only check some basic parameters like .is_authenticated etc ?

Comment: for avatar you probably have some profile model right? use http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile to get it. Also you can just write your own processor, which'll put profile into context

Answer (score 0):

using additional user data in your templates is easy:

`{{ user.get_profile.foobar }}` where foobar is one of your profile's fields.
But make sure to have set `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'yourprofileapp.YourProfileModel'`  in `settings.py`. 
For more info see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users