# User permissions for Django module

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-permissions

I'm having a small issue with my permissions in my Django template.

I'm trying to, based on permissions, show an icon in the menu bar for my project.  I want to have it so that if the user has the permissions to add a new follow-up to the project, they can see the icon, if they don't have that permission, then do not display the link.

My permission syntax is `follow.add_followup`, which I got from printing `user.get_all_permissions()`.

I have tried this code in my template:

```
...
{% if user.has_perm('followup.add_followup') %}
<li><a href="{% url followup-new p.id %}">Log</a></li>
{% endif %}
...
```

But when I display the template, I am presented with this error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /project/232/view/
>
> Could not parse the remainder: '(followup.add_followup)' from 'user.has_perm(followup.add_followup)'

Any thoughts?  This has been giving me a headache! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried this code in my template:

This kind of complex decision-making goes in the view functions.

Or it goes into the context which is then presented to the template.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdjango%5D+context

[When to use context processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880940/when-to-use-context-processor)

Do this in your view

```
def my_view( request ):
    followup= user.has_perm('followup.add_followup')
    # etc.
    return render_to_response( template, {'followup':followup,... )
```

Then your template is simply

```
{% if followup %}
<li><a href="{% url followup-new p.id %}">Log</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The reason I was trying it in the template, was because I didn't want to show icons that the logged in user, couldn't use.

Comment: You can create a boolean value in the view function and use a simple {%if%} in the template to display or not display.

Comment: Not really true or helpful, see answers below.

Answer (score 11):

Since you are using the Django permission system, it's better you use the followingg template syntax...

```
{%if perms.followup.add_followup%}your URL here{%endif%}
```

EDIT: Django automatically creates 3 permissions for each model, 'add', 'change' and 'delete'. If there exists no model for adding a link, then you must add the permission from related model, in the model class Meta... Likewise:

`somemodels.py`

```
class SomeModel(Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
    permissions = (('add_followup','Can see add urls'),(...))
```

In the Django auth user admin page, you can see your permission. In the template layer, permission is presented with the basic Django style,

```
<app_label>.<codename>
```

which, in this case, will be like:

```
{%if perms.somemodels.add_followup%}your URL here{%endif%}
```

If there is no model, related to the job you wish to do, the add the permission to a model...

In your template, you can write

```
{{perms.somemodels}}
```

to seal available permissions to that user, where `somemodel` is the name of the applicaton that you add your permission to one of its models.

Answer (score 2):

Django documentation detailing answer #2: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#id9

> The currently logged-in user's permissions are stored in the template variable {{ perms }}. This is an instance of django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper, which is a template-friendly proxy of permissions.

Comment: Thank you... this is by far the most useful answer!

Comment: Updated link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions - works for Django 1.5 to 1.7 (which is latest at time of writing).

Answer (score 2):

This is my very simple solution, in your template add this:

for example:

```
.......

{% if 'user.can_drink' in user.get_all_permissions %}
   {{ user }} can drink.
   .......
{% else %}
   {{ user }} can´t drink.
    ........
{% endif %}

.......
```