# how to get request.user in a TemplateTag

Tags: django, django-templates

How does one get in the value of request.user into a TemplateTag?

In the file myproject/news/templatetags/news_tags.py I have:

```
from django import template
from myproject.news.buildnews import BuildNewsList
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import http
from django.contrib import admin
from django.template import RequestContext

register = template.Library()

def news_now (context):
    #who = request.user  ## this doesn't work
    news = BuildNewsList()
    entries = news.buildnewslist()
    return {'entries': entries, 'who': who, }

register.inclusion_tag('news_list.html', takes_context=True)(news_now)
```

Separately I have a file news_list.html and overall the templatetag works. I just haven't been able to pull in the value of request.user in this templatetag.

Would appreciate any pointers.  Thanks. Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `django.core.context_processors.request` in your `settings.CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`? If so, make the first argument to the tag the request object and then you should be fine.

Answer (score 12):

... it could look like this:

```
 u = context['request'].user
```

Answer (score 1):

If that tag `takes_context`, then after adding **django.core.context_processors.request** to settings.CONTEXT_PROCESSORS there will be context['request'].user available.

Moreover, after adding **django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth** to  settings.CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, there will be context['user'].

Answer (score 0):

Just to be a little clearer on the description of the solution.

In your settings module, set (or create) the CONTEXT_PROCESSORS variable like so:

```
CONTEXT_PROCESSORS  = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'
)
```

Then in your view templates you can simply use
    **{{ user.username }}**
to refer to your currently logged in user object.

This works because the django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth module adds the '**user**' variable to the context dictionary. This is nearly equivalent to:

```
ReqCon = RequestContext(Request, {'user' : Request.user})
html = t.render(ReqCon)
return HttpResponse(html)
```

See SO thread: [Always including the user in the django template context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547/always-including-the-user-in-the-django-template-context)