# Always send the User information in every Django template

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-registration

I used a pre-built example templates for Django registration and I noticed that for those pages, Django understands `user` and I do things like `user.is_authenticated` and `user.username`.

I tried looking at the `views.py` code in both Django registration and the `django.contrib.auth.views`, but I couldn't figure out how those two always sent the `user` information to the templates.

I could could always explicitly send the `user` Context information to every view, but that would be violating the DRY principle.

I tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/269249/1150923), but I get an error saying

```
Put 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' in your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting in order to use the admin application.
```

And even if I placed the above path inside `settings.py` like this

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'doors.processor_file_name.user',
)
```

my templates still doesn't know about `user`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547/always-including-the-user-in-the-django-template-context/4815619 Duplicate

Comment: You have to use [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) which for some reason no one mentioned in linked question (so I apologize for vote to close).

Comment: No problem. I guess I should write down the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that every time I was using `render_to_response` in my `views.py`...

```
def order_all( request ) :
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    return render_to_response( 'doors/order/list.html', { 'orders' : orders } )
```

the [dictionary isn't a `RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#id2). Using a `RequestContext` will automatically include the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, which in my case will include `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`, which will pass along the `user` information to the every template.

So in other words, I just need to change the code above to this

```
def order_all( request ) :
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    return render_to_response( 'doors/order/list.html', context_instance = RequestContext( request, { 'orders' : orders } ) )
```

Don't forget to import `RequestContext` too

```
from django.template import RequestContext
```

It also turns out I don't need to explicity include `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` (or write my custom `doors.processor_file_name.user`) in the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` because [`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` is included by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS)

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but for anyone else who runs into this problem, you could use "render", instead of "render_to_response":

```
def order_all(request):
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'doors/order/list.html', { 'orders': order })
```

This also negates the need to import RequestContext. According to the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/), "render" is the same as "render_to_response", but has a context instance argument that forces the use of RequestContext.