# django username "disappears" when going in another view

Tags: django

Before I start, I'd like to point out that I have already surfed half of the internet in search of a possible solution, but nothing really solved my problem. That said, I'm quite the beginner in Django and Python so this could be a simple problem and maybe I'm just too dumb to figure it out.

So, here's the thing. I'm working on a project for college and I have to make a website that emphasises primarily backend. I chose Django as a framework and so far I've been able to have new users register and also log in and out. The problem is maybe not dramatic, but annoying for me at least. To be more clear, After a user logs in, I want to show his name in the top bar alongside the logout button.

So, the log in panel is as such:

[LoginPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59p03.png)

This part is fine, I just hit Log In and it works.

Then I get here:

[LoginUser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3di4a.png)

As you can see, at first, the username is displayed in the top bar alongside the logout. But if I click on "Whatever" or the username itself, it goes away. This may have something to do with the fact that initially, when the username is still visible, I'm in the url "login_user", which in urls.py uses the view "login_user". Once I click on either of those mentioned above, I wanted it to switch to a template called "user_panel.html", but I guess that could be a problem as well. Here is how it looks:

[UserPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZu3Z.png)

The view "login_user" looks like this:

```
def login_user(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'main/user_panel.html')

        else:
            return render(request, 'main/login.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'main/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
return render(request, 'main/login.html')
```

The username is displayed in "user_panel.html" with "{{ user.get_username }}".

Like I said, this could be a really elementary problem, but I simply can't get my head around it, really beats me. Thank you in advance for any possible help.

EDIT:

In settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

So, user.get_username is used in user_panel.html like this:

```html
<li>
  <a href="{%url 'main:user_panel'%}">
    <div style="font-size:1.5em; color:lightblue">
     <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i> <font size="5" face = "Ubuntu" color="white">{{ user.get_username }}</font></div>
  </a>
</li>
```

user_panel view:

```
def user_panel(request):
template = loader.get_template('main/user_panel.html')

return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

Now it shows the username, but everytime I click, downloads something:

[Downloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjlyV.png)

Comment: Can you add your `TEMPLATES` variable from the settings to the question? The current answers aren't necessarily "wrong", but I don't think it should be necessary to do anything to get the user into the template, with the default `TEMPLATES` set when you start a Django project.

Comment: I just edited it.

Comment: That's what I have in a recently created project, and `{{ user }}` works without any other configuration. Can you show the template, or at least the part where `{{ user.get_username }}` is being used? Edit: And what view is being called when you click "Whatever"?

Comment: I'll edit right now. When I click "Whatever" I use the view "user_panel" which just loads the template "user_panel.html". Guess that could be a problem?

Comment: Well, the problem shouldn't be the template, because it is being successfully used when you render it from the login view. How do you render the template in the `user_panel` view?

Comment: Just edited, in user_panel I just return an HttpResponse.

Comment: Ok, that's it then. Use `return render(request, 'main/user_panel.html')`, like in the other view. To get the user into the context you need the request, because that's where the user comes from (`request.user`).

Comment: Oh, thanks so much, that worked! But now if I click on "Whatever" or the username it downloads a file everytime, nothing specific, just a kind of blank file named "download". I'll post a pic in a moment

Comment: No problem, I actually learned a bit from this too. The download thing is odd, but I don't know what it might be. Try adding spaces after and before the `%` symbols in the `href` for the link.

Comment: I edited that part out of my last comment, because it turns out [you can actually have `div`s inside links in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct). Did you also add the spaces in the `href`? In any case, this is now a whole different question...

Comment: Ops, I found out why. Small mistake, instead of render in the user_panel view, there was still HttpResponse, I hit ctrl-z there by accident and boom :). Happens sometimes, then I search for bugs like a madman. Thank you for your time

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

> The username is displayed in "user_panel.html" with "{{
>   user.get_username }}".

It seems you forget to pass `user` to your template:

```
return render(request, 'main/user_panel.html', {'user':user})
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1064621/194586 if you want to include the user in all template contexts

Comment: Unfortunately it keeps disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace `user.get_username` with :
 `request.user.username`

or

`request.user.get_username`

Comment: I also tested this solution before, but unfortunately doesn't change much.

Comment: try to render your template like this:  return render(request, "main/user_panel.html", context).